# How To Detect PS3 Browser?

Tags: javascript, playstation3

So my website is getting a lot of traffic from PS3 browsers (says Google Analytics), I had my girlfriend test this out on her PS3 and the website looks horrible on a flatscreen tv and a smaller tv, this isn't the problem though, I'm looking for a way to detect the PS3 browser and put it into Javascirpt kinda like this:

```
if (ps3browser) {
/* Blahblahblah */
}
```

I know this is possible because Google Analytics does it and detects browsers:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect PS3 via user agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779631/redirect-ps3-via-user-agent)

Comment: You should really consider using some different CSS to make it more applicable to all kind of browsers, no matter what resolution they use.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment actually but thanks for the advice. It's just that the PS3 browser is depreciated and loads css and JavaScript weirdly sometimes, so I needed to make a workaround for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PS3 browsers contain `PLAYSTATION` in their User-Agents, so you could check the agent of the browser and act on that.. something like :

```
var agent = navigator.userAgent;
if (agent.indexOf("PLAYSTATION") != -1)
  //PS3 browser
```

Comment: Best answer :) thank you. So something like this would work?:

var agent = navigator.userAgent;
if (agent.indexOf("PLAYSTATION") != -1) {
  // Code here
}

Comment: @insanewolfhd and is exactly what the duplicate says

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's great :) I didn't see the post, sorry.